Chrome imprime el literal a la consulta: console.log() no el parámetro entre paréntesis
Buen día. Empiezo a programar javascript y al tratar de imprimir en chrome el típico console.log("Hola"); ya sea con comilla simple o doble recibo un literal y no el parámetro interno. Esta es la salida que obtengo: console.log ("Hola"); console.log ("Hola todos"). He buscado en internet y no puedo dar con la respuesta. Gracias.

Buenas, puedes pasar el código que estás usando, y la copia de la salida de la consola, o en su defecto, una imagen ?

No entiendo la salida, al ingresar por la consola de chrome console.log("Hola"), ¿te da como salida hola o console.log("Hola') y Hola?

interesante te explico como usar console.log

Gracias, con las respuestas recibidas me doy cuenta lo amplia que es la programación. Ruego disculpas porque soy principiante, pero las respuestas recibidas me ayudaron a entender mejor.

@cardina perfecto, si alguna de estas respuesta te resulto positiva puedes dar click en el gancho para marcala como respondida. que tengas un excelente fin de año y no dudes en preguntar si no sabes como hacer algo.

El problema que mencionas ocurre porque probablemente estás escribiendo el código de manera incorrecta o intentando ejecutarlo en un lugar inadecuado (por ejemplo, directamente en la consola de Chrome de forma incorrecta). También podría ser causado por algún error de formato al copiar y pegar, etc.
Te dejare este ejemplo de como usar console.log() y todas sus variantes correctamente:


// Uso básico de console.log
console.log("Hola"); // Imprime: Hola

// Varias entradas en una sola línea
console.log("Hola", "a todos", 123, true); // Imprime: Hola a todos 123 true

// Mensaje con interpolación de variables
let nombre = "Juan";
let edad = 30;
console.log(`Mi nombre es ${nombre} y tengo ${edad} años.`); 
// Imprime: Mi nombre es Juan y tengo 30 años.

// Mostrar objetos
let persona = { nombre: "Ana", edad: 25, profesion: "Ingeniera" };
console.log(persona); 
// Imprime el objeto completo

// Variantes de console:
console.warn("Este es un mensaje de advertencia"); // Advertencias (color amarillo)
console.error("Este es un mensaje de error"); // Errores (color rojo)
console.info("Este es un mensaje de información"); // Mensajes informativos
console.debug("Este es un mensaje de depuración (puede no mostrarse en algunos navegadores)");

// Tabla con datos
console.table([
    { Nombre: "Carlos", Edad: 28 },
    { Nombre: "Luisa", Edad: 34 },
]);
// Imprime una tabla interactiva con los datos

// Contadores
console.count("Proceso"); // Imprime: Proceso: 1
console.count("Proceso"); // Imprime: Proceso: 2

// Agrupación de mensajes
console.group("Grupo de mensajes");
console.log("Mensaje dentro del grupo");
console.log("Otro mensaje dentro del grupo");
console.groupEnd();

// Temporizadores
console.time("Tiempo de ejecución");
// Aquí algún código que quieras medir

setTimeout(() => {}, 5000); // Tiempo de ejecucion.
 
console.timeEnd("Tiempo de ejecución");
// Imprime: Tiempo de ejecución: X ms



Entonces:
Si al escribir console.log("Hola"); obtienes un literal como salida (es decir, la línea completa console.log("Hola");), puede que estés:

Escribiéndolo como un literal dentro de un editor de texto y no ejecutándolo correctamente.

Asegúrate de que lo estás escribiendo dentro de un archivo JavaScript (.js) o en la consola de desarrollo de tu navegador.

Copiando el código incorrectamente dentro de la consola del navegador.

Si pegas todo el código de una vez, asegúrate de presionar "Enter" después de pegar para ejecutar el comando.

Usando comillas incorrectas o espacios extraños.

Elimina cualquier espacio innecesario o reemplaza las comillas si parecen "diferentes" (copiadas de fuentes externas).


ejemplo del uso simple en HTML:


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Prueba Console.log</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        console.log("Hola, este es un mensaje de prueba.");
    </script>
</body>
</html>



Y en la consola sería así (el escenario que describes):

podrás tambien encontrar mayor informacion en:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console

A la pregunta le faltan detalles y cualquier respuesta es pura especulación. Probablemente sea otra cosa y trabajaste en vano. No hay que responder preguntas así.

@CandidMoe por que tu lo dices?, no lo creo, la pregunta tiene todo lo necesario para elaborar una buena respuesta sobre el uso de console.XXX y de paso se le enseña a la comunidad el alcance ... pero claro no lo aceptaras ... por que no cumple tus canones ...

Francisco te agradezco tu empatía por los que somos novatos. Siempre digo que cuando ya una persona sabe, se le olvida que algún día fue principiante. No es que al novato no quiera hacer la tarea investigando. Se hace pero a veces es frustrante quedar varado en lo elemental. Por eso se agradece la ayuda del tutor o maestro. GRACIAS!!!

@cardina para eso estamos, pero si te recomendaría, que seas más detallista en las preguntas y dudas, para que usuarios como Candid no se vean frustrados por algo mal colocado que no termina de entender.

@FranciscoIALover, fiestaaaa!!! me alegra tu vuelta, espero que sea con cambios, no les des el gusto de volver a dejarte afuera, siempre un "dandy", siempre un grande, evita a los tóxicos, solo has lo que mejor haces!!!.

Siii tengo bastante tarea pendiente... pero aquí estamos para ayudar a lo nuevos y a los no tan nuevos ...
